# Connection to PostgreSQL with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am just starting to learn node.js to build a chat application on my website. I am trying to connect to pgsql from node.js. I found how to connect to mysql via:

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'xxxxxx',
  database : 'rest',  
});
connection.connect();
```

can someone help me with connection to pgsql from node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the top result from a Google search of `PostgreSQL node.js`  will do the job: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: hey
I tried to install it. but get an error, Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Comment: This has nothing to do with pg itself. You must've hit the recent breaking npm update. Check http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more.

Comment: got it to work.. thanks. can you help me on how i can set up a basic ajax polling via node.js?

Comment: With due respect, you seriously need to get into the habit of Googling. It will result in much faster returns for you and save others a lot of time too.